# Как с помощью z-index сверстать картинку?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мучался над этим заданием очень долго так и не понял как его делать, объясните как, с помощью z-index, разместить блоки

Comment: Покажите, что получилось у Вас?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если из 4 элементов, то никак.

Если из 5, то одну линию режем и делаем без границы, а остальное просто.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.a, .c { width: 8em; height: 2em; }
.b, .d, .e { width: 2em; height: 8em; }
.a, .b, .c, .d, .e { border: 1px solid; position: absolute; z-index: 2; }

.a { left: 1em; top: 2em; background: blue;   }
.b { left: 6em; top: 1em; background: green;  }
.c { left: 1em; top: 6em; background: yellow; }
.d { left: 2em; top: 1em; background: orange; z-index: 1; }
.e { left: 2em; top: 5em; background: orange; border-top: none; height: 4em; }
```

```html
<div class=a></div>
<div class=b></div>
<div class=c></div>
<div class=d></div>
<div class=e></div>
```